# Kafka JDBC source connector for oracle not working

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using the ojdbc8.jar in the plugins. Running the JDBC source connector for oracle 18c (standalone mode) runs some logs and then freezes to one point:

```
Mar 02, 2020 4:38:50 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: The (sub)resource method createConnector in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method listConnectors in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method listConnectorPlugins in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource contains empty path annotation.
WARNING: The (sub)resource method serverInfo in org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.RootResource contains empty path annotation.

[2020-03-02 16:38:50,938] INFO Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@29357e3d{/,null,AVAILABLE} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler:744)
[2020-03-02 16:38:50,955] INFO Started ServerConnector@79c680dc{HTTP/1.1}{hdp-master.com:8083} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector:266)
[2020-03-02 16:38:50,956] INFO Started @22725ms (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server:379)
[2020-03-02 16:38:50,956] INFO REST server listening at http://hdp-master.com:8083/, advertising URL http://hdp-master.com:8083/ (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:150)
[2020-03-02 16:38:50,956] INFO Kafka Connect started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:55)
[2020-03-02 16:38:51,025] INFO AbstractConfig values:
        batch.max.rows = 100
        catalog.pattern = null
        connection.attempts = 3
        connection.backoff.ms = 10000
        connection.password = [hidden]
        connection.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.2.220:1521/orcl
        connection.user = c##hamza
        db.timezone = UTC
        dialect.name =
        incrementing.column.name = ID
        mode = timestamp+incrementing
        numeric.mapping = null
        numeric.precision.mapping = false
        poll.interval.ms = 3600000
        query = select * from c##hamza.owais;
        quote.sql.identifiers = ALWAYS
        schema.pattern = null
        table.blacklist = []
        table.poll.interval.ms = 60000
        table.types = [TABLE]
        table.whitelist = []
        timestamp.column.name = [MODIFIED]
        timestamp.delay.interval.ms = 2
        topic.prefix = LITERAL-VAL-
        validate.non.null = true
 (org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig:238)
```

It doesnt close after this too. The connector is as follows:

```
name=LITERAL_VALUES
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
#key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
#value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
value.serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
connection.user=c##hamza
connection.password=admin
poll.interval.ms=3600000
tasks.max=1
table.whitelist=OWAIS
connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.2.220:1521/orcl
mode=timestamp+incrementing
incrementing.column.name=ID
timestamp.column.name=MODIFIED
timestamp.delay.interval.ms=2
topic.prefix=LITERAL-VAL-
```

There is no data travelling to any new topic. The database table OWAIS has following discription (as in the picture):
[image]

Comment: Note: `table.poll.interval.ms` doesn't match your config... You sure those properties are correct? Did you bother to look at the /status endpoint of the connector? Maybe it OOM'd or other SQL error

Comment: I would also question the `timestamp.delay.interval.ms=2` for a timestamp column with precision 0 = seconds.